# What to do about a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/293703). Unfortunately it was rejected for the following reason:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

That is rather abstract. It does not really tell me, what is supposedly incorrect about my edit.

I realize I may not have provided enough of an explanation in the edit summary.  But I still think that the current answer is incorrect and needs to be edited. I would happily explain to the reviewers why I think so. I wasted enough time on debugging it and I just want to help others.

What should I do now? Edit it again? (Without really knowing why my first edit was rejected.) Post a new answer? I would just leave a comment to the answer, but I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: I would have rejected it as "Radical change" - you changed something in the "core" of the answer making it something else.

Comment: I only changed it to what the original author probably intended. Only that he did not know how ember.js really (i.e. slightly counter-intuitive in this case) works. The problem is the people who rejected my edit may not know anything about ember.js.

Comment: This might be true but still, the author of the post is the one who should fix it. Comment is the right way to inform him of his mistake, as Jon says in his answer below it's really not that hard to reach 50 reputation then you can post such comment. It was wrong for this long, it can wait several more days.

Comment: @MartinPuppe - I disagree with your question down vote and if I bother to get the reputation I will up vote it. I edited a clearly erroneous bit of code in an older question that **would not work at all** in it's previous state. The edit was rejected with the same ridiculous "incorrect or reply to comment" and a "too minor" reason. However it was not incorrect, not a reply to a comment and clearly wasn't minor as the code didn't work without it. My reputation compared to the poster probably took a role in the rejection. Sadly people are the best and worst thing about this whole system.

Comment: Now you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard How about editing a title which is inserting a tag into the title in the following format    Python - [question title]. I removed that tag and my suggestion rejected! I'm asking just to make sure in future when I work on an edit I know what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: @Ayman by itself, it is not wrong. **But** it can be rejected for two reasons: 1) when there are other obvious issues with the question that were not edited, or 2) lots of sequential edits of this kind which can be considered as rep farming and is frowned upon by many. If it was neither try again, and if still rejected raise this in the per site meta for discussion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It was neither. I think no need to try again. All I want to know if this way is correct or not, so if it's not, I'll learn from my mistake that's all. you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21252327) thank you.

Comment: @Ayman yes it was valid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're changing the original author's code, and not in an obvious "it's just a typo" way. Edits to other people's posts should generally be just clarifying the original authors message - not *changing* the message.

In this case, I suggest you add a *comment* to the answer to explain why you think *they* should change it.

EDIT: I hadn't noticed the final line of the question. Given that commenting is the correct approach here (IMO), just answer questions elsewhere until you've got 50 rep, then add the comment.

Comment: As I said I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @MartinPuppe: Sorry, I'd missed that. In that case, remember that you want to come back to it, and add enough answers to get enough rep to comment. It shouldn't take long to get 50 rep.

Comment: That is not really going to help anyone who sees the wrong answer in the meantime.

Comment: @MartinPuppe: True, but as I say, it shouldn't take long.

Comment: @JonSkeet somehow, I feel a bit nervous when _you_ say getting 50 rep shouldn't take long